# Error when using each on a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails, I'm trying to work with a hash. When I do an `each` on it, I get an unexpected result. I'm trying to access the 'name' for each element.

I start with a hash called `some_files`, this time with just 1 element in it:

```
logger.debug some_files  
# Outputs this:  {"0"=>{"name"=>"index.html", "contents"=>""}}
# Ok cool, the first level of this array seems to only have 1 element called "0".
```

Now I want to iterate through it (since sometimes it will have more than 1 element).

```
some_files do |some_file|
  logger.debug some_file
  # Outputs this: ["0", {"name"=>"index.html", "contents"=>""}]
  # Weird, why do I get "0" still? And why does it appear to be a separate element?

  logger.debug some_file.name
  # Outputs an error: NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for ["0", {"name"=>"index.html", "contents"=>""}]:Array):
end
```

Comment: If you downvote, please at least give a comment about why you are downvoting. I've looked at the docs and don't see my error. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-each

Comment: shouldn't it be `some_file.last["name"]`?

Comment: how can you iterate over `some_files` without using `each`? I'm referring to `some_files do |some_file| ...`

Comment: If you post, please at least give a question about what you are asking. I've looked at the post and don't see any question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you iterate over a Hash using .each in Ruby, *both* a key and value are passed to the Block. If you specify only 1 parameter, this will be an Array containing key and value instead. So, proper use would be:

```
hash = {"0"=>{"name"=>"index.html", "contents"=>""}}

hash.each do |key, value|
  puts "key = #{key}, value = #{value}"
  # => key = 0, value = {"name"=>"index.html", "contents"=>""}      
end
```

Since `value` is also a Hash, you can iterate it in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

The first output:

```
{"0"=>{"name"=>"index.html", "contents"=>""}}
```

is a hash, not an array. Your second output is an array.

```
some_files.each do |some_file|
   # you get
   a = ["0", {"name"=>"index.html", "contents"=>""}]
   # which is an array, containing a string and a hash and you could get the name via:
   name = a[1]["name"]
end
```

You get `undefined method name` because the array does not have a method name.

As far as

> Weird, why do I get "0" still? And why does it appear to be a separate element?

I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Thanks sytycs - corrected "array" to "hash" in the question. How come `each` splits up the `0` and the second part? Wouldn't each just go through the first level of the hash?

Comment: @DonnyP some_files is a nested hash. Usually you pass two block variables `key` and `value`. If you pass just one, then Ruby somehow has to make up for it so it puts everything into an array represented by that block variable